# In SQL is there any benefit to using multiple views rather than a single view?

Tags: sql-server-2008, view

I am currently making a view to replace my current stored procedure and was wondering if there is any benefit in creating multiple views, where the fetch has to join the different views, rather than a single view where the fetch doesn't have to use any joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two point of views for this

1. Suppose in your application, there is something reusable which is written already in the stored proc and is reusable in another stored proc as well. So you can shift that part in the view and call the view in both stored Procedures and futher you can filter down to your desired result.
2. Unnecessary use of views can cause performance issues. Because views donot accept input parameters so it is going to select all matching rows depending on your join Inner/Left

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit I could imagine would be if the different views have independent value. In other words, could they be useful in other places on their own? If not, just create a single view.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you add indices to the view (thereby materializing it), it doesn't make a difference really, since the query analyzer will treat them alike. Therefore you should use whatever is best for your specific application (even if that's only in terms of maintenability or readability).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple views would allow you to to be more granular when you are selecting who can see what (if you are using views for security purposes).  Basically you could say group A can only see the data in View A, Group B can only see data in View B, and so on.

If you are using Indexed Views to improve performance I would stick with one view that does the joins for you.  Since this data will be persisted it can save you the cost of performing the join.